# disable 3.5mm microphone jack

Tags: microphone, headphone-jack

Today I heard about an advice to cover your webcam and disable the microphone of your computer or laptop. I have taped off the webcam already, and now want to disable the microphone. I've set the input level to 0 in the system settings, but I would like to use a jack, one that has no function other than making the computer believe that a microphone is connected. This jack should be short and small, like those small usb bluetooth dongles.

Do you know if something like this exists, and where I can get it?

Comment: 1. Do you have a tinfoil hat? If not, you should get one. 2. Either disable those devices in the BIOS if those settings are available or disable them in Device Manager.

Comment: Btw, if you tape webcam, the adhesive glue may flow onto webcam glass after long period of time thus damaging the picture quality.

Answer (score 2):

Any audio parts store will have this item. Just buy a 3.5 jack.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't see a reason to be so much paranoid about privacy.
If you have a facebook or google or any online account as a matter of fact, you can very well forget about privacy.

If you still want to go ahead, just get a 3.5mm jack plug it in and leave its wire end open to air.
e.g. Cut jack off old headphones and plug it in.

This will send electronic disturbances or noise as microphone input.
You can try recording it(even if you try to touch the open end of wire, you will see noise being recorded)